# SQL SERVER Query result in CSV format is possible?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to get the query result in .CSV file format from SQL SERVER 2000 and above versions?

If so can we use this feature from an asp.net application to get the result in CSV format?

If so how can we do this?

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/ looks applicable. I don't know SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly loop through the DataTable results and build the CSV file yourself.